# Seven out of Seven odds

Tags: probability

My neice just gave birth to her 7th child.  All children were single child births (no twins etc...). No artificial methods were used (invitro,  fertility drugs etc.) 
All 7 are boys!
What are the odds of this occurance?

Comment: What are the factors to be considered? If only genders, and assuming each gender has $\dfrac12$ probability, then this event has $\dfrac{1}{2^7}$ probability.

Comment: Actually, researches have shown that in most industrialised countries, the probability of a boy is abouts 0.51. So $0.51^7$.

Answer (score 0):

There are seven child births and each of the child can be either a girl or a boy. So the number of possible ways one can give births is $2*2...$ 7 times $=2^7$

Giving all 7 births as boys is only one possible way

So number of odds are $2^7-1$

The probability of this odd event is 
$\frac {2^7-1}{2^7}$

Comment: I don't really get this answer. What?

Comment: I have edited answer @Studentmath . Can you please point now the thing you havent understood

Comment: What do you mean by number of odds? Also, in your computation of number of possible ways of giving birth, you are taking into consideration the order of births - not necesserily true. Anyhow, I don't think this has anything to do with what the question asked.

Comment: I think you quotient is flipped. The answer you give is way too close to $1.00$.